# WSO2 ESB version 4.9.0 CAR file problems

Tags: wso2, esb

We are facing an issue where we have a proxy,sequence and a mediator in the project. Some how the changes are not getting reflected for the mediator class when we bundle the project as CAR file and deploy from wso2 admin. We have to delete tmp,restart server,deploy the same CAR multiple time to have the code running. We are using wso2 esb version 4.9.0. Is there a fix to this issue or is it a bug ? please help your support is need as we are kind of in a showstopper situation.

Thanks
DS

Comment: AFAIK this should work OOB. what is the exact error that you get?

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is no error as such. But its like the mediator does not take the latest changes into account. We have to delete from tmp and re-deploy the CAR till the time its working.We are using jdk1.7.79 just incase it helps. But its like a show stopper for us.

Comment: Can you change your jdk in to 1.8 and try it out ? Hope it will solve the problem.